# PostgreSQL using BitmapAnd instead of composite index

Tags: postgresql, performance

I have `table2` and I'm limiting my result by date range `date_col` and integer column `col1`. I get different plans between using `BETWEEN` and `IN()` for date range.
Plans do not change if I add more days.

My main question is why PostgreSQL decides to use `BitmapAnd` when there is composite index for both of those columns?

If possible, I would also like to know why it gives different plans between those two methods for limiting my set by date range and if I can set some server options in order to avoid this.

### Testing:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  FROM table2
 WHERE date_col BETWEEN '2017-07-10' AND '2017-07-11'
   AND col1 = 332
```

Gives (before `ANALYZE`):

```
Index Scan using table2_date_col_col1_idx on table2  (cost=0.43..341.69 rows=39 width=44)
  Index Cond: ((date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (date_col <= '2017-07-11'::date) AND (col1 = 332))
```

After using `ANALYZE` on table (freshly generated):

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table2  (cost=2252.82..4165.42 rows=498 width=45)
  Recheck Cond: ((col1 = 332) AND (date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (date_col <= '2017-07-11'::date))
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=2252.82..2252.82 rows=498 width=0)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..145.95 rows=7670 width=0)
              Index Cond: (col1 = 332)
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_date_col_idx  (cost=0.00..2106.37 rows=100194 width=0)
              Index Cond: ((date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (date_col <= '2017-07-11'::date))
```

This query:

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  FROM table2
 WHERE date_col IN('2017-07-10', '2017-07-11')
   AND col1 = 332
```

Before `ANALYZE`:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table2  (cost=9.65..317.36 rows=78 width=44)
  Recheck Cond: ((date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (col1 = 332))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_date_col_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..9.63 rows=78 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (col1 = 332))
```

After `ANALYZE`:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on table2  (cost=13.96..1925.32 rows=498 width=45)
  Recheck Cond: ((date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (col1 = 332))
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table2_date_col_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..13.84 rows=498 width=0)
        Index Cond: ((date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (col1 = 332))
```

Interesting is that before analyze, both queries give different estimate for rows returned.

### Schema + data:

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 (id serial PRIMARY KEY, date_col date,
                     some_col int, col1 int, col2 text);
```

Function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.random(integer, integer)
 RETURNS integer
 LANGUAGE sql
AS $function$
   SELECT ($1 + ($2 - $1) * random())::int;
$function$
```

Data:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (date_col, some_col, col1, col2)
SELECT date_col::date, random(1000000,7000000), random(200,400), md5(random()::text)
  FROM generate_series(1,50000) AS num
  CROSS JOIN generate_series('2017-07-01'::date, '2017-07-31'::date, '1 day') AS date_col
```

Indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON table2 USING btree(date_col);
CREATE INDEX ON table2 USING btree(col1);
CREATE INDEX ON table2 USING btree(date_col,col1);
```

### EDIT - adding explain analyze

`WHERE date_col IN()` is faster when there is less dates used. `table1` has even number of rows per day and there is 31 days (2017-07). `table1` is basically the same as `table2`, just more rows (about 200m).

What is disturbing is that `IN()` will keep using composite index, despite stats clearly showing that there are only 31 distinct values for this column and using index on said column alone should be faster. This is maybe not so drastic here (75s vs 81s), but in production for other tables I saw cases when planner would decide to use composite index (date_col, some_random_col), even tho I only gave date condition in WHERE. This makes query go from about 1 minute to whooping 40 minutes. Ridiculous. It gets fixed after I run analyze in order to include freshly added day into statistics (same day I used in WHERE condition), but it still makes no sense to me. I suppose I'm getting slightly offtopic but it does feel related to planner not using statistics in sane way.

```
--WHERE date_col >= '2017-07-10' AND date_col <= '2017-07-11' AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=289814.12..498299.85 rows=60165 width=45) (actual time=2874.749..72574.670 rows=56662 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: ((table1.col1 = 332) AND (table1.date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (table1.date_col <= '2017-07-11'::date))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 64327757
  Heap Blocks: exact=32714 lossy=663337
  Buffers: shared read=734520
  I/O Timings: read=60654.424
  ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=289814.12..289814.12 rows=60165 width=0) (actual time=2854.244..2854.244 rows=0 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared read=38469
        I/O Timings: read=593.932
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..17510.42 rows=947980 width=0) (actual time=413.941..413.941 rows=876992 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (table1.col1 = 332)
              Buffers: shared read=2400
              I/O Timings: read=73.380
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_date_col_idx  (cost=0.00..272273.37 rows=12985280 width=0) (actual time=2403.607..2403.607 rows=13200000 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ((table1.date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (table1.date_col <= '2017-07-11'::date))
              Buffers: shared read=36069
              I/O Timings: read=520.553
Planning time: 76.269 ms
Execution time: 72597.548 ms

--WHERE date_col >= '2017-07-10' AND date_col <= '2017-07-21' AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=17601.80..1723659.99 rows=365510 width=45) (actual time=398.685..73908.546 rows=339677 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: (table1.col1 = 332)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 63519900
  Filter: ((table1.date_col >= '2017-07-10'::date) AND (table1.date_col <= '2017-07-21'::date))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 537315
  Heap Blocks: exact=42548 lossy=663337
  Buffers: shared read=708285
  I/O Timings: read=63032.731
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..17510.42 rows=947980 width=0) (actual time=380.480..380.480 rows=876992 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (table1.col1 = 332)
        Buffers: shared read=2400
        I/O Timings: read=34.086
Planning time: 7.691 ms
Execution time: 73973.701 ms

--WHERE date_col >= '2017-07-01' AND date_col <= '2017-07-31' AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=17747.41..1723805.61 rows=947980 width=45) (actual time=359.913..75058.918 rows=876992 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: (table1.col1 = 332)
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 63519900
  Filter: ((table1.date_col >= '2017-07-01'::date) AND (table1.date_col <= '2017-07-31'::date))
  Heap Blocks: exact=42548 lossy=663337
  Buffers: shared read=708285
  I/O Timings: read=63848.616
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..17510.42 rows=947980 width=0) (actual time=346.336..346.336 rows=876992 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (table1.col1 = 332)
        Buffers: shared read=2400
        I/O Timings: read=34.437
Planning time: 8.258 ms
Execution time: 75179.169 ms



--WHERE date_col IN('2017-07-10', ..) AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=1281.84..209617.15 rows=60165 width=45) (actual time=33.533..7441.378 rows=56662 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 3253762
  Heap Blocks: exact=22072 lossy=33898
  Buffers: shared hit=2 read=56130
  I/O Timings: read=6801.373
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_date_col_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..1266.80 rows=60165 width=0) (actual time=25.858..25.858 rows=56662 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
        Buffers: shared hit=2 read=160
        I/O Timings: read=5.959
Planning time: 7.957 ms
Execution time: 7450.346 ms

--WHERE date_col IN('2017-07-10', .., '2017-07-21') AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=7785.30..960333.44 rows=365510 width=45) (actual time=171.661..47546.257 rows=339677 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11,I_CUT_HERE,2017-07-21}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 26010391
  Heap Blocks: exact=40928 lossy=271210
  Buffers: shared hit=20 read=313091
  I/O Timings: read=41089.435
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_date_col_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..7693.92 rows=365510 width=0) (actual time=159.538..159.538 rows=339677 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-10,2017-07-11,I_CUT_HERE,2017-07-21}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
        Buffers: shared hit=20 read=953
        I/O Timings: read=28.047
Planning time: 7.738 ms
Execution time: 47596.678 ms

--WHERE date_col IN('2017-07-01', .., '2017-07-31') AND col1 = 332
Bitmap Heap Scan on public.table1  (cost=12906.25..1365283.04 rows=604948 width=45) (actual time=445.607..81144.267 rows=876992 loops=1)
  Output: date_col, some_col, col1, col2
  Recheck Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-01,2017-07-02,I_CUT_HERE,2017-07-30,2017-07-31}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
  Rows Removed by Index Recheck: 63777327
  Heap Blocks: exact=39804 lossy=666081
  Buffers: shared hit=54 read=708350
  I/O Timings: read=60703.758
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on table1_date_col_col1_idx  (cost=0.00..12755.01 rows=604948 width=0) (actual time=430.652..430.652 rows=876992 loops=1)
        Index Cond: ((table1.date_col = ANY ('{2017-07-01,2017-07-02,I_CUT_HERE,2017-07-30,2017-07-31}'::date[])) AND (table1.col1 = 332))
        Buffers: shared hit=54 read=2465
        I/O Timings: read=67.264
Planning time: 9.017 ms
Execution time: 81261.378 ms
```

### Stats

`table1` is the same as `table2`, just more rows per day.

```
postgres=# SELECT attname, null_frac, avg_width, n_distinct, most_common_vals, correlation FROM pg_stats WHERE tablename = 'table1';
 attname  | null_frac | avg_width |  n_distinct  | most_common_vals | correlation
----------+-----------+-----------+--------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------
 int      |         0 |         4 |           -1 |                  |    0.996684
 date_col |         0 |         4 |           31 | {2017-07-07,2017-07-03,2017-07-08,2017-07-28,2017-07-04,2017-07-15,2017-07-20,2017-07-18,2017-07-31,2017-07-23,2017-07-14,2017-07-16,2017-07-22,2017-07-25,2017-07-19,2017-07-21,2017-07-01,2017-07-05,2017-07-12,2017-07-26,2017-07-11,2017-07-30,2017-07-06,2017-07-10,2017-07-09,2017-07-24,2017-07-17,2017-07-27,2017-07-29,2017-07-02,2017-07-13} |   0.0346347
 some_col |         0 |         4 | 6.58472e+006 | {1096591,1131422,1176742,1205762,1267732,1358307,1793233,1897958,1958800,1979780,2020229,2187352,2222144,2306378,2367818,2445771,2506148,2590445,2600271,2752586,2945764,3024254,3201950,3412218,3530060,3616631,4001881,4033122,4142542,4200890,4216142,4218113,4461939,4486968,4525355,4592945,4704906,4839527,4967659,5055096,5077240,5412984,5455464,5561802,5573389,5648549,5657678,5666687,5782171,5869402,5900299,5953811,6166736,6232273,6249154,6388286,6482146,6525559,6527271,6555494,6682407,6772179,6823587,6936062,6944575,6953775} | -0.00714019
 col1     |         0 |         4 |         1665 | {234,211,356,255,325,381,393,266,375,259,278,232,303,334,337,246,249,254,279,317,329,301,319,365,221,256,300,240,285,309,347,201,231,357,399,208,220,223,260,268,269,332,352,270,328,342,367,297,314,219,272,287,324,218,224,267,283,299,321,388,229,242,284,298,302,389,397,233,237,307,358,380,217,222,235,236,247,313,323,366,368,206,213,250,251,282,296,373,245,349,354,355,369,372,248,252,280,322,345,204} |   0.0849631
 col2     |         0 |        33 |           -1 |                  |  0.00675247
```

Comment: I recommend to use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, then you also see the true cardinalities at each operation.

Comment: @W.Mann I have added results of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`, but I do not feel like they answer why Postgres makes such nonsense plans. It actually gets worse as it shows that they aren't really adjusted to what statistics would make me believe they should.